# Expectation of the minimum value among a Poisson-distributed-number-of-draws from a Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, order-statistics

I would like to calculate the expectation of the minimum value among a Poisson-distributed-number-of-draws from a normal distribution.

Appreciate some guidance in formulation of the expectation.

Below is a derivation where n is deterministic (not distributed by Poisson)

[Expectation of minimum of $n$ samples from Gaussian distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2584779/expectation-of-minimum-of-n-samples-from-gaussian-distribution?rq=1)

Comment: Did you mean minimum of the Poisson-distributed-number-of-draws and a normal distribution?

Comment: I effectively want an expression for the "expected extrema" similar to https://mbhs.edu/~ansarma/stat.pdf, but rather than N (num of draws) being deterministic, it itself follows the Poisson distribution.

Comment: Can you find an expression for $f(n):=\mathbb E\min(U_1,\dots,U_n)$ where the $U_i$ have standard normal distribution? If so then proceed with calculation of $\mathbb Ef(N)$ where $N$ has Poisson distribution. Note that you must provide a default for $f(0)$.

Comment: Well I can (link above, and another here) but deriving an extension of this where n is poisson-distributed is not trivial ... how would you suggest to "proceed with calculation"?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2584779/expectation-of-minimum-of-n-samples-from-gaussian-distribution?rq=1